# What should I look for when buying a Lensatic Compass

Tags: compasses

Lensatic Compasses seem to be priced from $5 to $100 USD.  What features should I look for when buying one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lensatic Compasses are often used by the military, because the are:

- Reliable
- Durable
- Compact
- Stealthy (more on this)

### The things that I would look for in a lensatic compass are:

1. Solid outer casing
2. Sighting guide with thin slot or notch
3. Compass latching cover.
4. Electrically buffered needle

   - Some lensatic needles are buffered with oil, which can leak.
5. Radioactive "**Tritium**" powered illumination

   - **Do Not** use a compass with **Radium**
6. Easy to read bezel for night time bearings and triangulations.

### Stealth

One of the great advantages to the lensatic compass is their use in night time navigation. The compass bezel is illuminated with a radioactive isotope. All modern lensatic compasses use **Tritium**, older compasses used to use **Radium**, but their use was linked to cancer, so don't use them.

The radioactive tritium particles are low energy beta particles and are not harful for external use, (they cannot pass through clothing or skin). As long as you don't swallow them you are fine.

The reason for the illumination is so that the compasses can be used without any external light source. The military, especially special forces, love this. It allows for "dark" navigation.

### Other information

All radioactive isotopes have a half life. And Tritium's is 12 years, so in 12 years your compass will be half as bright as it is the day you bought it, then 12 years later, another half life. And so on.

Links to other information...

- [Lensatic Compass Guide](http://lensaticcompass.blogspot.com/)